# Unable to debug Flutter app using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4 for flutter development, latest Flutter and Dart plugin installed. I am not able to debug my application. When I try to do it, debugger just shows a message "Waiting for a connection". Also sometimes when I run app , dart.exe stops and I lose hot reload functionality. I tried flutter doctor. it gives the following output,

```
[√] Flutter (on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US, channel alpha)
• Flutter at E:\Flutter\flutter
• Framework revision d36e2f6191 (9 days ago), 2017-06-21 15:09:10 -0700
• Engine revision b0dee695ec
• Tools Dart version 1.24.0-dev.6.7

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 25.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Brajendr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-25, build-tools 25.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)

[√] Android Studio (version 2.2)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Gradle version 2.14.1
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.1)
• Flutter plugin version 15.0
• Dart plugin version 171.4694.29

[√] Connected devices
• Cloud 4G Star • 0123456789ABCDEF • android-arm • Android 5.0 (API 21)
```

Comment: I would suggest filing an issue on the Flutter github.

Comment: Seems you are testing on Windows only, did you try on a different OS, e.g. Linux? Do you see the same behavior there?

Comment: I will try on a different OS and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions :

1. maybe you should update intellij idea 2019.2.1
2. use debug app lanunch your app

   it's here: [idea debug btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxVTO.png)